# Using nginx, how to conditionally hide multiple set-cookie response headers coming from backend?

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx config using `fastcgi_pass`. I'm sure it would work the same with `proxy_pass`.

For anonymous/guest users, I wish to hide the `set-cookie` response header set by php's `session_start()` (I also hide the `cache-control`, `expires` and `pragma` headers), but for logged-in users (and when an anonymous user is logging in), I wish to pass all the `set-cookie` headers sent by the backend.

I made the app set a special header (`X-SPECIAL`) I can inspect in nginx to decide which kind of response it is - for guests or not.

When the backend sends a single `set-cookie` header, I successfully pass it only when needed using `$upstream_http_set_cookie`. But when the backend sets multiple cookies using multiple `set-cookie` response headers, `$upstream_http_set_cookie` contains only one value, so the client only sees one cookie. This results in login not working.

How to get all values in `$upstream_http_set_cookie`?
Or alternatively, how to conditionally set `fastcgi_hide_headers`? I know that `hide_headers` does not support variables, and it seems it cannot be set differently per-request.

Do I have to use openresty and lua?

My config:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m;

map $upstream_http_x_special $not_store_in_cache {
  default "1";
  guest "0";
}

map $upstream_http_x_special $maybe_set_cookie {
  default $upstream_http_set_cookie;
  guest "";
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        set $not_from_cache "";
        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$) {
            set $not_from_cache "1";
        }
        if ($cookie_phpsessid != '') {
            set $not_from_cache "1";
        }
        # conditionally don't serve request from cache
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $not_from_cache;
        # conditionally don't store response into cache
        fastcgi_no_cache $not_from_cache$not_store_in_cache;
        fastcgi_cache my_cache;
        fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri;
        fastcgi_cache_valid any 1s;
        # serve from cache while generating next response
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_503;
        # single request to backend, no matter how many requests for same resource.
        fastcgi_cache_lock on;
        # store in cache regardless of response headers
        fastcgi_ignore_headers expires cache-control set-cookie;
        # remove these headers from response before passing back to client.
        fastcgi_hide_header pragma;
        fastcgi_hide_header expires;
        fastcgi_hide_header cache-control;
        fastcgi_hide_header x-special;

        # Fake conditional hide response header by always hiding and
        # conditionally adding it back.
        # Works only when there is a single "set-cookie" header,
        # fails when backend sets multiple cookies.
        fastcgi_hide_header set-cookie;
        add_header Set-Cookie $maybe_set_cookie;

        # standard code for php backend
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to set `$not_from_cache` that avoids the problematic `if`. Not a complete answer but may lead to one with some more help:

```
map $request_method,$cookie_phpsessid,$uri $not_from_cache {
    default 0;
    ~*^POST,[^,]*,.*\.php$ 1; # match php POST request
    ~*,[^,]+,.*\.php$ 1;      # match php request with $cookie_phpsessid set
}
```

Comment: that `if` is not a problem. The problem is that for some responses I want `fastcgi_hide_header set-cookie;` and for some I want to pass along the set-cookie headers. If there is only one set-cookie header, then I can always hide, and then conditionally add it back. But if there are multiple set-cookie headers, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Z.T. Did you ever find out how to resolve this? I too am having the issue that only one value from the header set-cookie is picked up instead of the multiple that are returned from the backend